# References on Rupa and Arupa Jhana through Brahma Vihara

Tags: reference-request, metta, brahmavihara

I am looking for freely available resource on achievement of Jhana through Brahmavihara. What are such references?

Also I would like to dig deeper into what Bhanthe Vimalasiri has written on the subject. So references on his teachings are greatly appreciated, but so would be works by other teachers.

Comment: Related: [Is there a compassion only Buddhist path?](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/4118/254)

Answer (score 1):

Upasaka Suminda Sirinath S. Dharmasena,

*May Atma be able to proper trust that Upasaka is well, healthy any heedfull?*

Especially Notes here give further crosslinks, aside of the Sutta it self:

[SN 46.054](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/sn/sn46/sn46.054.than_en.html#fn-3) and a linked in another question [AN 04.125](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.125.than_en.html#fn-3)

Also [Sankhitta Sutta: In Brief
(Good Will, Mindfulness, & Concentration)](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an08/an08.063.than_en.html) might be of interest.

And here maybe useful Bhant Nyanadassanas teaching: [From mettā Jhāna to nibbāna](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/nanadassana/metta_en.html#nibb) and a Sutta and commentat that supports that: [DN.09](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/dn/dn.09.0.than_en.html) and at least [The Limits of the Unlimited Attitudes - 
The Brahmaviharas on the Path to Awakening](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/beyond_en.html#ch7) by Bhante Thanissaro with many links and crossreferences.

All collected in "[Metta-Boom just fills Heaven and Hell](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,2034.msg9049.html#msg9049)"

Here some of [Ven.Mahāsi Sayadaw comments](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,2346.msg10217.html#msg10217).

In regard of Bhanthe Vimalasiri, best to ask Upasaka [Micro](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/5466/mirco?tab=profile), he is surely be found on any forum of other tapapals, charts or equal Buddhist communities and as disciple (till not so long mentioned as such) of Bhante, he always loved to share in this regard.

*(Note: This is a gift of Dhamma not meant for commercial purpose or use for other wordily gains.)*

Comment: Is Upasaka @Mirco still reachable via Bu-SE?

Comment: Their [profile says](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/5466/mirco?tab=profile) that their most recent visit to this site was October 2015, so no.

Comment: Who knows. And delighted Devas are always around to share merits and bring people together in Dhamma, Nyom Chris. Sadhu für Aufmerksamkeit und Zuvorkommenheit.

Answer (score 0):

this for first part of your question.
[metta 1 sutta](https://suttacentral.net/en/an4.125)